Как настроить локалхост между основной и виртуальной машиной?
Развернул RabbitMQ на виртуальной машине VMware. На этой же виртуальной машине стучусь в реббит http://192.168.143.1:15672  и всё замечательно. Но с основной машины достучаться по этому адресу не получатся (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) На виртуалке порты открыл(не знаю, нужно ли было) В принципе кроме портов ничего не делал...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне всё-таки открыть реббит с мейновой машины, если он развернут на виртуалке?
Очень буду благодарен развернутому ответу
